# Is There a Way to Implement EventTarget with Plain JS?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying (perhaps in vain) to come up with a way to use the publish-subscribe pattern while **a)** using *no* libraries and **b)** minimizing boilerplate code in modules that use it. So far the best I've come up with is this:

```
var handle = document.createElement();
var unsubscribe = AwesomeModule.subscribe(handle);

handle.addEventListener('awesome', function() {
    console.log('awesome');
});
```

This will work pretty well, except that people using AwesomeModule might be confused by having to provide a random DOM element that isn't used as an element.

I tried the following and it doesn't work too well:

```
var handle = Object.create(EventTarget);
var unsubscribe = AwesomeModule.subscribe(handle);

handle.addEventListener('awesome', function(){
    console.log('awesome')
});
```

I get `TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'addEventListener'`. Interestingly enough, it doesn't seem to look in the prototype chain even though handle has EventTarget as its prototype.

Why doesn't this work? Is there a way implement EventTarget with pure JS? Can it be done in a single line of code that won't horrify users of AwesomeModule?

**EDIT:** I don't know why it didn't occur to me last night, but I suppose EventTarget being an interface means that it doesn't have implemented code. What's confusing is that in the Chrome debugger console `Object.create(EventTarget)` makes an object that *appears* to have addEventListener in is prototype chain. Maybe its lying. Can anyone explain this behavior? Can anyone explain why W3 chose not to make EventTarget a concrete "class"?

Comment: addEventListener is not supported in Internet Explorer 6, 7 and I think 8. You need to use attachEvent. For a library function that supports both you can use the one at: //--- http://ejohn.org/projects/flexible-javascript-events/

Comment: @MattBall Its a core part of browser JS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.

Comment: @jeff I'm not concerned with browser compatibility right now. I'm having this problem with Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the answer to my original question is "yes." Since JavaScript doesn't have an inheritance model like Java which does compile-time checks for legal implementation, I suppose any Object can implement an interface merely by having methods with the same name. However, doing this would constitute making a library since the addEventListener code isn't implemented in EventTarget (I had previously assumed it was). Since there seems to be no cross-browser way to get a vanilla EventTarget, I will probably use window.addEventListener in conjunction with custom events.

Answer (score 3):

Although this is 9 years old, I'd like to answer. `EventTarget` is the constructor function and not an EventTarget **object**. If you want to create a new EventTarget, you need to to exactly this: `new EventTarget()`. You can use this object to add, remove and dispatch Event.

If you want to create your own class that **is** an EventTarget, you need to use the JavaScript class syntax.

```js
class MyTarget extends EventTarget {
   constructor(name) {
      super();
      this.name = name;
   }
}

let t = new MyTarget("foo");
t.addEventListener("clack", e => console.log("clack on " + e.target.name));

t.dispatchEvent(new Event("clack"));
```

This will show "clack on foo".

You can't do this with old, handmade inheritance like this:

```js
function MyTarget(name) {
   this.name = name;
}
MyTarget.prototype = new EventTarget();   // Won't work!
MyTarget.prototype.constructor = MyTarget;
```

It won't work, you'll get a TypeError: Illegal invocation.

Comment: Good answer and exactly what I was looking for, thanks for providing an up to date answer to a nine year old question! (Also, it sent me down a rabbit hole about whether really it wasn't possible using old prototypal inheritence, but you are right and it wasn't.)

Answer (score 1):

The source is located here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/trace-viewer/src/base/event_target.js&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=18

If you can't modify it, you can always replicate it.

Comment: That's interesting. Does this mean you can have a "concrete" vanilla EventTarget in Chromium?

Comment: new link : https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/ui/webui/resources/js/cr/event_target.js?q=event_target&dr

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple set of routines that works well.
with [a small polyfill for IE9 and 10](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent#Polyfill), support is decent.

you can incorporate these functions into your project as needed, i don't think it constitutes a library, or i wouldn't post this.

```
var on = addEventListener.bind(window),
 off = removeEventListener.bind(window),
 emit = function(name, val) {
    dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(name, {
        detail: val
    }));
};



// demo:
on("test", function(e){ alert(e.detail);});
emit("test", "Number is " + Math.random());
```

i don't think it can get much simpler (~180 chars) without sacrificing speed or library compatibility.

Comment: That looks really handy, but it still uses DOM elements. I may end up using something like this, but I'm not sure I consider it an answer to my questions.

Comment: where does it use any DOM elements?

Comment: You're using the window as a global event dispatcher. Like I said, your way is helpful because it hides the DOM shenanigans from the module user, but I was really hoping for a way to bind events to a non-DOM object.

Comment: Well, a basic EventEmitter doesn't use window (which isn't an Element imho), but that would require at least a small library. Node.js has a really nice open source EventEmitter, i would bite the bullet use it if you're concerned about window causing issues. There are several smaller ones listed on bower and microsjs. This is just an arguably better approach to the same thing you're going for in your question...

Comment: @dandavis do you have any links to these libs?